# AngularJS - load a vendor script at module dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to create an AngularJS module containing a directive and a service that use moment.js.

Is there a way to load this library when the module is injected as dependency ?

The goal is to load moment.js when the application inject the module as a dependency, and avoiding any pairing between the final application and the vendor script.

(I know that angular-moment exists, I have similar problem with other libs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's injector runs the factory function of your service when it is first injected. You could load the external script there.

This won't come "freely", though, when you use the service, because the script loads asynchronously, and so you will have to always guard against the script not yet being loaded.

For example, you could do something like this in your service's factory function:

```
.factory("foo", function($q) {

  function loadScript(src) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    return script;
  }

  var loadPromise = $q(function(resolve) {
    loadScript("foo.js").onload = function(){
      resolve();
    }
  });

  return {
    load: function() {
      return loadPromise;
    },
    doFoo: function() {
      // TheFoo is the object created by foo.js
      return TheFoo.doFoo();
    }
  };
});
```

Then, when you use it, for example in the controller, you have to wait until it has loaded:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, foo){

   // foo.doFoo(); <== this will fail because it has not yet loaded

   foo.load().then(function(){
     $scope.prop = foo.doFoo();
   });
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEP64Ivr8JDDZQgSZFHZ?p=preview) for illustration

Comment: I would like to have a solution without promise as it must be propagated in the application, but that seems to be the only way

Comment: @AlexB, I took your question to mean that you wanted to have an Angular service wrapper service in a separate file than the underlying library. If you delivered them in the same file, then clearly this would not be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I really want it as a wrapper service. I realised that every parts of the application should be load in parallel, so promise must be used even if this promise is  propagated in the rest of the application, making the code less friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your libraries registered, you can do conditional injection for example like this:

```
app.service('myDependencyService', function($injector) {
  if (your_condition) {
    return $injector.get('dependency1');
  } else {
    return $injector.get('dependency2');
  }
});
```